# Android: Error while compiling : I changed Exoplayer library from r2.5.3 to 2.9.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, exoplayer

Error while compiling : I changed Exoplayer library from r2.5.3 to 2.9.0.

now the Gradle is syncing properly but showing compilation error when I try to rebuild the project.

Detailed error log:

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/daffodil-111/Desktop/GitProjects/app/app/build/intermediates/transforms/FirebasePerformancePlugin/preprod/13
>
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
>
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete.
>
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException

Android studio

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0):

Actually the above mentioned problem is not due to the updation of exoplayer library, its because it requires JAVA_1.8 version which uses the incremental build while compiling, but when i try to build with it, that causes build failure as some other already added dependency does not support incremental build feature.

fix ==> Disable the incremental build feature of JAVA_8